# How to change color of bootstrap glyphicon .?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How do I change the color of my star glyphicon? My code is

```
<span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty " onclick = "addToFav()">      </span>
```

I am calling a javascript function on the click of glyphicon. I also want to change the color of the glyphicon as shown in the image below. I tried changing the background color of the gyphicon but it doesn't give me the desired output.
**Update"' On changing the style.color of the glyphicon, it just changes the color of the glyphicon but doesn't fill the glypicon with the desired color. The first image is the original glyphicon. The second image is the desired result. The third image is the glyphicon on changing the background color of the glyphicon. The fourth image shows what happens to glyphicon on changing style.color of glyphicon to red. 
 [image: My Glyphicon]
[image: Desired glyphicon after click][image: Faulty result on changing the background color on click][image: On changing the color of the glyphicon]

Comment: In gyphicon you can only change `color` not `background-color`.

Comment: Use an SVG with `fill` to do that.

Comment: How do I use SVG? Can you share some code .

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Comment: I already found an easy solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this.

```
 <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty " onclick = "addToFav(this)"> </span> 
<script>
    function addToFav(ths){
        ths.style.color = "#ffea00";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't fill the star with yellow color. It just changes the color of the glyphcion . I have updated the question with the image on changing the style.color to red.

Comment: Use this icon.. <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" onclick = "addToFav(this)"> </span>

Comment: This gives me a glyphicon with black color. How do I change the color to yellow. Also, how do I change the class on the click of the button.

Comment: Got it . I can change the color property to change change the color fill.

Comment: How do I change the class of the glyphicon on the click of the button?

Comment: ask in  another question comment that link here

Answer (score 1):

```
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" style="color:red;background-color:blue;padding:10px"></span>
```

you can change how ever you want like color,background-color,padding change it

Comment: I already tried changing the background color and color. It doesn't give me the desired output.

Comment: i will share fiddle wait

Comment: That will be of great help. Also note that I am using glyphicon-star-empty. The code snipped which you provided above use glyphicon-print.

Comment: in above link you can find two colors one is icon color, icon background color

Comment: I think, there is some confusion. The desired output is the second image above.

Comment: But how do I change the class of the image glyphicon on the click of the button. Initially I want to display the empty star.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to change the star from a black outline to a filled yellow star? If so, then you'll need to change not just the style to set the `color`, but you'll also need to replace the class `glyphicon-star-empty` with the class `glyphicon-star`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked out the best for me. In my class list for glyphicon, I added both, the class for filled star and the class for the empty star. The empty star class is written after the star class and thus it overrides the filled star class and hence, initially I get the empty start on the screen. The code is as follows

```
<span id="star-glyp"class="glyphicon glyphicon-star glyphicon-star-empty" onclick = "addToFav()">
```

On clicking this glyphicon, I call addToFav() function. In this function, I am doing two things to produce the desired output. First, I am changing the color of the glyphicon to yellow. Second, I am removing the glyphicon-star-empty class from my class list. The code is as follows:

```
 function addToFav(){

                ths = document.getElementById("star-glyp");
                ths.style.color="YELLOW";
                ths.classList.remove('glyphicon-star-empty');
}
```